# Question about Kaluza-Klein excitations

Tags: string-theory, spacetime-dimensions, beyond-the-standard-model, branes, kaluza-klein

In Randall Sundrum (RS) model-type 1 :
[A Large Mass Hierarchy from a Small Extra Dimension](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9905221), it’s mentioned that:

> This result contrasts sharply with the scenario of large extra dimensions for solving the
> hierarchy problem with a product structure for the full spacetime, where the Kaluza-Klein
> splittings are much smaller than the weak scale, possibly smaller than an eV.

Where they mean by the scenario of large extra dimensions , the ADD model  [The Hierarchy Problem and New Dimensions at a Millimeter](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9803315).

So what does it mean by Kaluza-Klein excitations ?

Why are they light in ADD model while they are at TeV scale in RS model , or how can they be calculated in RS model for instance ?

Any help is appreciated !